# Custom Info Window for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'd like to make a custom Info Window for Google Maps for iOS like the photo below. Is it possible to extend GMSOverlay like GMSMarker, GMSPolyline, and GMSPolygon do to create custom graphics?

[image]

Comment: Custom info window (== window on click) OR custom marker (==always there)?

Comment: http://kevinxh.github.io/swift/custom-and-interactive-googlemaps-ios-sdk-infowindow.html                   this blog explains how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please mark the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who's trying to add buttons to a custom view representing info window - it seems to be impossible to do, because Google Maps SDK draws it as an image or something like this. But there is a quite simple solution:

1. You have to create a custom view with buttons and whatever you need to be displayed in your info window.
2. Add it as a subview in your **mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker)** method. You can set a position of a custom view by getting a coordinates of a marker tapped with a help of **mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(marker.position)**
3. Your custom view possibly has to change it position by following camera position, so you have to handle **mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition)** where you could easily update your custom view position.

   ```
   var infoWindow = CustomInfoView()
   var activePoint : POIItem?

   func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
       if let poiItem = marker as? POIItem {
       // Remove previously opened window if any
           if activePoint != nil {
               infoWindow.removeFromSuperview()
               activePoint = nil
           }
           // Load custom view from nib or create it manually
           // loadFromNib here is a custom extension of CustomInfoView
           infoWindow = CustomInfoView.loadFromNib()
           // Button is here
           infoWindow.testButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.testButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .AllTouchEvents)

           infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(poiItem.position)
           activePoint = poiItem
           self.view.addSubview(infoWindow)
       }
       return false
   }

   func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {

       if let tempPoint = activePoint {
           infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(tempPoint.position)
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Default information window also shown. and how to show indicator on custom information pointing to clicked marker.

Comment: @RajAggrawal please what is `POIItem`

Comment: @King It may be your wrapper class to contain coordinates and name, for example.   It has to be the subclass of GMSMarker.  Have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

Comment: The tool tip has its own background which is white. Can I make it clear ? Because I’ve tried and nothing seems to be working

Comment: I guess it should work as it is usual subview you add to your ViewController's view, but I cannot check this at the moment.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to create this view programmatically?

Comment: Sure, just assign to infoWindow your UIView created programmatically.

Answer (score 105):

You will want to use the `markerInfoWindow` delegate method along with setting the `infoWindowAnchor`.

When you create your marker, set the anchor:

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = MARKER_POSITION;
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44f, 0.45f);
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomMarkerImageName"];
```

then create the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
  InfoWindow *view =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
  view.name.text = @"Place Name";
  view.description.text = @"Place description";
  view.phone.text = @"123 456 789";
  view.placeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customPlaceImage"];
  view.placeImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-.08);
  return view;
}
```

In the example above I created a xib
[image]
and I loaded that xib, returning the resulting `UIView`. You could instead construct a `UIView` using just code.

Comment: skarE, did you also have to make a corresponding InfoWindow class?
Would it be possible to get a copy of the XIB file you made?
Thanks!

Comment: I have made a UIButton using this..but not able to click it

Comment: can u send to me the xib file?

Comment: @RahulMishra the info window is a rendered version of the UIView, which is why the view does not recognise user interaction

Comment: how to update the data of info window if it is rendered on map?

Comment: Hello all, when i am trying to add custom infowindow in my google map view then i am getting following error.                                                   
                                                                                                               This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future. Any help

Answer (score 3):

You can pass this type of UIImage as icon like below

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
 GMSMarker *location = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
 location.title = @"Location Name";
 location.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_icon.png"];
 location.map = mapView_;
```

For more details [see this Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker).

If you want this type of image after marker pressed than you must have two type of images of single place.

1st image marker icon only.

2nd image is marker with place detail.

marker icon loaded when mapView initialise like above code.

And Second Image marker with place detail you have to load like this inside marker pressed `delegate` method using `For-Loop` and `NSMutablearray` by checking `marker.title` to know which marker is pressed.

```
 - (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
 {

 }
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen that but I'm looking to customize the whole Info Window when the user touches a marker.

Answer (score 3):

Swift version, example version of marker custom class:

```
class CustomMarker: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var seperator: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "CustomMarker", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}}
```

Thanks to [How to initialise a UIView Class with a xib file in Swift, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513271/how-to-initialise-a-uiview-class-with-a-xib-file-in-swift-ios) you can add extension to UIView so you don't need cast

```
protocol UIViewLoading {}
extension UIView : UIViewLoading {}

extension UIViewLoading where Self : UIView {

// note that this method returns an instance of type `Self`, rather than UIView
static func loadFromNib() -> Self {
    let nibName = "\(self)".characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init).last!
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil).first as! Self
}
}
```

And in your delegate:

```
    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let customMarker:CustomMarker = CustomMarker.loadFromNib()
    customMarker.titleLabel.text = marker.title
    customMarker.descriptionLabel.text = marker.snippet

    return customMarker
}
```