# Ios-googlemaps integration

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google maps sdk in ios. Can we place a image in the info window which pop up when user taps the marker. 
Usually infowindow provides a title and a snippet for some description. But i want to insert a image related to that place in that info window. how to do that in ios

Comment: Check out the google maps API documentation too, there's a lot of infomration.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: @ManthanPatel Thank you.. In the documentation it says the info window content can be html snippet,can we include html code for displaying images in it

Comment: Try to put it inside a

infowindow.setContent('<div><img src="rute.jpg"');
infowindow.open(map,marker); hope it helps.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ManthanPatel currently mac is not there. i will try...

Comment: OK. Fine. I am putting this as an answer. Please accept if you find it useful and you get your solution.

Comment: @ManthanPatel i am using it in a ios application, html code is not accepting there

Comment: You can see my other [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps/16767124#16767124) on how to create custom info windows for the Google Maps iOS SDK.

Comment: @skarE I have seen your solution . I am new to ios development, can you please give me more details for that. I understood that you have created a xib window and calling it when the marker is pressed. But can you give me some more clarity on how to integrate the xib window to infowindow anchor

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it inside a

```
infowindow.setContent('<div><img src="rute.jpg>"');
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

I hope it helps.

Check out the google maps API documentation too, there's a lot of infomration.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: You missed closing ">"