# adding custom object (e.g rating with DYRateView) to GMSMarker via (?) userdata

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, uiimage, google-maps-sdk-ios

I would like to display rating with `DYRateView` in info window when user tap on `GMSMarker`.

I would like, that final result looks something like presented in the image below.

So far I have red the [GMSMarker Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker) I think the only way is via `userData` field. I have tried it with adding simply NSString on UIImage but it was not displayed. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

```
UIImage * bar =[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];
[sydneyMarker.userData setUserData:bar];
```

Please be lenient, because I am a newbie to iOS development.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I have red this: [Custom Info Window for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps)

and watched the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY

[image]

having in mind (from SDK documentaiton):

> Note: The info window is rendered as an image each time it is
>   displayed on the map. This means that any changes to its properties
>   while it is active will not be immediately visible. The contents of
>   the info window will be refreshed the next time that it is displayed.

i will probbably go for self-made info window basing very much on tutorial from mentioned video.