# Custom Google Maps Marker View

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to display custom UIView instead of the default one for Google Maps Marker (iOS SDK).
There is a property to set icon but icon it is not enough in my case.
I receive an image from backend which should be placed inside the custom marker:
[image]

I know that I could completely modify MarkerInfoWindow but it is not what I need:
[custom-info-window-for-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps)

How to override marker view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is turned out that I have to use the Icon property only.
And in order to accomplish my goal a have to render two images into one using Graphics Context.

Comment: hey alexey, have you achieved this? if yes can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps GMSMarker has a property `iconView` which allows us to set custom `UIView` for marker. You need to create xib within which your image from backend and other data to be displayed can be managed. Below code snippet can be used to set a custom marker view.

```
- (void)setCustomMarker {
   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:51.5 longitude:-0.127 zoom:14];
  _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  self.view = _mapView;
  _mapView.delegate = self;
  UIImage *house = [UIImage imageNamed:@"House"];
  house = [house imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
  _londonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:house];
  _londonView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
   CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
  _london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
  _london.title = @"London";
  _london.iconView = _londonView;
  _london.tracksViewChanges = YES;
  _london.map = self.mapView;
}
```

In your case `londonView` should be a `UIView` which you can set to iconView property.

[Google maps implementation for custom marker section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#use_the_markers_iconview_property) with things to consider while implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create custom view as per your requirements (with .xib and .swift) file**

*MapIconView.swift & MapIconView.xib*

```
class MapIconView: UIView {
    class func createMyClassView() -> MapIconView {
        let myClassNib = UINib(nibName: "MapIconView", bundle: nil)
        return myClassNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! MapIconView
    }
}
```

**2. Set custom marker iconView**

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

let markerView = MapIconView.createMyClassView()
marker.iconView =  markerView
marker.map = self.mapView
```

**3. The groundAnchor didn't show up at all**

```
marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```