# Creating a custom marker menu in google maps api V2

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create an app similar to Waze but I don't know how to make a pop up menu for markers
like [this](http://www.shinyshiny.tv/gallery/2012/10/top_alternatives_to_apple_maps/1-waze-app.jpg)

The system I'm trying do is that if a user decides to mark their current location or double tap anywhere on the map a menu will pop up with a selection of my own markers.
I'm using the latest version of Google Maps for Android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the pop up with an Adapter, just call the setInfoWindowAdapter method and override the following methods, like this:

```
mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_marker_location, null);
                TextView tvTitle   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMarkerTitle);
                TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMarkerSnippet);
                tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                return rowView;
            }
        });
```

You can read the documentation of the [InfoWindowAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html) interface.

Comment: Thanks is there an objective C version?

Comment: I think this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps