# How to detect camera position for google map in swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I get to know after searching that idleAtCameraPosition and didChangeCameraPosition this methods are called when the map moves .
How can i write this method for swift? I have set delegate to CLLocationManagerDelegate and GMSMapViewDelegate but still this methods are not called. I have written method as below:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
                print(position)
}

func mapView(mapView:GMSMapView!,idleAtCameraPosition position:GMSCameraPosition!)
{
    print(position)

}
```

But my method is not getting called.
Also I want to customise info window just like done here : [Custom Info Window for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps) . But can't find the methods how to do same in swift. I am new to swift s o not getting this.

Comment: Have you assigned value to your mapView delegate? ex: `self.mapView.delegate = self` ?

Comment: @ztan Yes, i have done that, still its not working

Answer (score 7):

Maybe too late, but you must extend the class with GMSMapViewDelegate. For example:

```
class NearMeViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate
```

Then, how Ztan says, you have to delegate your map with:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

With this, the method `didChangeCameraPosition` will respond every time that that camera's position is changed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Guillaume Fache

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the GMSMapViewDelegate at the top of your class

put self.mapView.delegate = self in your viewDidLoad()

and then you can use this method

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {

        // You can use the position.target for get the current camera position

}
```