# Custom marker view not showing in swift google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I want to show custom marker view on my map.
I got reference from  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16767124/2849443

```
var pin:GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude))
pin.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)
pin.icon = UIImage(named: "img_map_pin")
pin.map = mapView?
mapView?.selectedMarker = pin
```

My method for custom view marker is as shown below

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
    var arr:NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MarkerView", owner: self, options: nil)
    var view:MarkerView = arr[0] as MarkerView
    view.IBlblAddress?.text = "text"
    return view
}
```

I have set delegate GMSMapViewDelegate and also mapView.delegate = self is set , still my method is not getting called. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.887, -87.622)//here you can give your current lat and long
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "flag_icon")
    marker.map = mapView

    self.view = mapView
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: @Pooja Shah is the above answer helped you?Update to others is important.

Comment: yeah, once you initiate your marker then you have to set the marker's map to the mapView you have created.