# UIView and GMSMarker joined together

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiview

Is it possible to stick a UIView to google maps GMSMarker? I am trying to implement custom infoWindow using Google Maps SDK for iOS and I want the created view to stick to GMSMarker when the camera of mapView is moving.

I have already done this calculating the movement of the marker and repositioning the custom infoWindow in .didChangeCameraPosition od GMSMapViewDelegate but this way my CPU usage goes as high as 95%.

I have been searching for a while and I can't find any phrase that would give me desired result. Any hint/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps). It might be of help.

Comment: I've already found it. The case is, this way the Google Maps SDK renders a UIImage as infoWindow, so there is no way for button action. I know, there is a delegate method that allows me to implement anything after the infoWindow is tapped but it is not the same.