# How to segue to a new ViewController from infowindow of Google Maps in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm trying to figure out this video:(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=573hrwiJJeo), and I'm still trying to implement it on my Swift project but unsuccessful a lot. I am really curious and I have two questions about it, anyone help?

1. How to create an "info icon" and "image" in the infowindow of Google Maps? (0:18)
2. How to click info icon, then segue to next viewController? (0:20)

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY) from Google can help you with that. It explains here how to place image inside the Info window, but not image only. It also disccused here how to design or make a custom info window. This video also includes the sample code in how to make it.

Here are the steps that you need in building Custom InfoWindow

- Construct a new NIB file named InfoWindow
- Create UIView subclass called CustomInfoWindow
- Configure UILabels with content and load photo

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps).