# Button click event inside a map marker info window

Tags: swift, google-maps

I want to create a info window for a Google map marker to provide a button click event inside the info window in my iOS application. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I found this video from 2013, hope this can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY

Comment: and another topic on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }
        let identifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        let myButton = UIButton()

        annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = myButton

        return annotationView
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. but i'm not using map kit.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that :\