# Custom google maps marker loading and updating very slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

I have to implement custom Google maps GMSMarker. I have referred [google documentation to create a custom marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#use_the_markers_iconview_property).

**Issue** which I am facing is whenever I want to update the marker it is taking significant amount of time (1 sec - 3sec) to update, which degrades user experience. I am **NOT** creating multiple markers I just have 2 markers in current implementation.

Here is the code which I am using to create marker :

```
- (void)showMarker 
{
     gmsMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds camera:camera];
     CLLocationCoordinate2D position = { latitude, longitude };
     marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
     marker.flat = YES;
     marker.iconView = [self setCustomIcon];
     marker.map = gmsMapView;
     marker.userData = slot;
}
- (UIView *)setCustomIcon
{
     Marker *view =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Marker" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
     /*
       few lines of code to set data
     */    
     return view;
}
```

**NOTE :**

1. I know I can create [custom info window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps) but it not what I am looking for.
2. GMSMarker has a property `tracksViewChanges` which stops tracking changes in marker view, when set to NO. But I cannot set it to NO as I need to update view when it is tapped.
3. This issue only comes if I set `iconView` property of marker, if I just use `icon` property and set an image to it, It works fine.

**EDIT :** Update Marker Code

```
- (void)updateMarker:(GMSMarker *)localMarker
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     self.previousSelectedMarker.iconView = [self setCustomIcon];
     localMarker.iconView = [self setCustomIcon];
     self.previousSelectedMarker = localMarker;
     self.slot = localMarker.userData;
      // update data
  });
}
```

Below image shows how much delay comes when I tap on a marker an update its image :

[image: issue]

Comment: when do you update marker ? Add updation code.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre I have updated the question with updation code.

Comment: Did you try removing    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() and updating the image without GCD

Comment: @gurmandeep Yes I did try that. No luck!

Comment: so in [self setCustomIcon]; you are loading a NIB file?

Comment: Ooops !! Yes, this was the error which I was doing. I just had to update the color but I was loading NIB file instead. Thanks!