# Set Button Title Using Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a google map which contains multiple buttons as markers, I set marker position & title using:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -7.0343237999999992, longitude: 110.42400399999997, zoom: 15)
self.mapView.animate(to: camera)

let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MapsWindows", owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as! MapsWindows

let markerView = infoWindow

for state in self.states {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(state.lat, state.long)
    infoWindow.titleButton.setTitle(state.name, for: .normal)
    marker.iconView = markerView
    marker.map = self.mapView

}
```

the position is correct, but button's title always set to latest index of array. So all of my buttons have the same title. How to make the button title appropriate order?

Comment: You got **many** `states` but only **one** button. What do you expect?

Comment: i have multiple buttons

Comment: In the loop there is one button: `infoWindow.titleButton`

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps

Comment: As @vadian mentioned, in the loop you are editing the same `infoWindow`, it is *not* related to the new instantiated `marker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, just put

```
let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MapsWindows", owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as! MapsWindows

let markerView = infoWindow
```

inside for loop