# Custom infoView for array of markers swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have an application where I am working with Googlemaps, I am able to create markers for all the coordinates needed but the issue I am facing now is I want to show a custom UIView when a user taps on a marker to show the info associated with that marker

```
func showFeaturedProperties(properties: [FeaturedProperties]) {
        self.properties = properties
        properties.forEach { (props) in
            var lat = Double(props.latitude!) as! Double
            var lng = Double(props.longitude!) as! Double


            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,
                                                     longitude: lng)
            marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            marker.isFlat = true
            marker.map = mapView
            if props.typeId == 1 {
                marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "_map_rent_icon")
            } else {
                marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "_map_buy_icon")
            }

            marker.setIconSize(scaledToSize: .init(width: 25, height: 25))
            marker.iconView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.markers.append(marker)
        }

    }
```

The above code shows the marker on the map, how can I show Details when the marker is clicked?

I have so far extended the `GMSMapViewDelegate`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        if let index = markers.index(of: marker) {
            let tappedState = properties[index]
            log(tappedState.id)
        }

        let infoView = BaseCardView()

        return infoView
    }
```

this does not work still any help is welcomed

Comment: How do you want the custom view to appear/be presented onto the screen?

Comment: @bsod like a tool tip. a UIView with the details contained in that coordinate

Comment: You don't need a custom view, Google Maps has a built-in info window (tooltip) for markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#add_an_info_window

Comment: I have some labels and imageview I want to add to the view

Comment: They're easy to customize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746765/custom-info-window-for-google-maps

Comment: I am unable to find the one that addresses multiple markers

Comment: What do you mean by a tooltip for multiple markers?

Comment: I have an array of markers on the map, so the examples I have been seeing does not highlight for such instance

Comment: So every marker has a tooltip that is always open?

Comment: More like every marker point has different content but I’m using a single uiview. Two tooltip cannot be opened

Comment: That's what the built-in tooltip does, a single view for the open marker.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create infowindow marker view with xib file

   ```
   import UIKit
   import GoogleMaps
   class InfoMarkerView: UIView {

   var view:UIView!
   var parentVC:StartRideViewController?

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: frame)
   setup()
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
   setup()
   }

   func setup() {
   view = loadViewFromNib()
   view.frame = bounds
   view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth
   view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
   addSubview(view)
   }

   func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
   let bundle = Bundle(for:type(of: self))
   let nib = UINib(nibName: "InfoMarkerView", bundle: bundle)
   let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
   return view
   }

   func UpdateView(marker:GMSMarker){
   // set values to labels here
   }
   }
   ```
2. Add GMSMapViewDelegate to your viewcontroller file

   ```
   var mapView: GMSMapView!
   var infoMarkerView:InfoMarkerView?

    if(latitude != 0 && longitude != 0){
                   let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                   let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

                   var myData = Dictionary<String, Any>()
                   myData["title"] = ridername
                   myData["snippet"] = ridertime
                   myData["photoUrl"] = photoUrl
                   myData["position"] = position
                   myData["accuracy"] = accuracy
                   myData["uid"] = riderUID
                   myData["status"] = riderStatus
                   marker.userData = myData


                   marker.title = ridername
                   marker.snippet = ridertime
                   marker.position = position
                   marker.iconView = self.showImageonMap(imgPath:photoUrl)

                   marker.map = self.mapView


               }

   // MARK: GMSMapViewDelegate method implementation

   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
   print("here")
   if infoMarkerView != nil {
       infoMarkerView?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay)
   {
   print(overlay.zIndex)
   print("User Tapped Layer: \(overlay)")
   if infoMarkerView != nil {
       infoMarkerView?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool     {
   //let update = GMSCameraUpdate.zoom(by: zoomLevel)
   //mapView.animate(with: update)

   if infoMarkerView != nil {
       infoMarkerView?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   infoMarkerView = InfoMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: marker.infoWindowAnchor.x, y: marker.infoWindowAnchor.y, width:180, height: 120))
   infoMarkerView?.parentVC = self
   // Offset the info window to be directly above the tapped marker
   infoMarkerView?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: marker.position)
   infoMarkerView?.center.y = (infoMarkerView?.center.y)! - 125
   infoMarkerView?.UpdateView(marker: marker)

   mapView.addSubview(infoMarkerView!)
   return true
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
   if infoMarkerView != nil {
       infoMarkerView?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
   if infoMarkerView != nil {
       infoMarkerView?.removeFromSuperview()
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am using GoogleMaps

Comment: Okay, would be expecting it